# Python nested for loop: outer loop is looping, but always with same value

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have the following code:

```
def TEST():
vals = [[0]*len(K_values)]*len(u_values)
for p in range(len(u_values)):
    u = u_values[p]
    for i in range(len(K_values)):
        K = K_values[i]
        vals[p][i] = u * K
return vals
```

`u_values` and `K_values` are 11-element long 1-D arrays. `vals` is a 2-D array of zeros that (should have) has its `[p][i]` element updated with `u * K` upon every loop.

The problem is that instead of changing the index p upon each (outer) loop, python always uses `p=0` - this means that upon every loop, only `u_values[0]` is ever used. At first I thought this was because the outer for loop was only executing once; however, when viewing the code output (`vals`), it is clear that the outer loop IS looping `len(u_values)` times; it's just always with `p=0` (otherwise, I would expect that only the zeroth column of the `vals` array would be nonzero).

Comment: I suggest modify the code:  l_u = len(u_values)... for p in range(l_u), and similar for the other loop. That will at least isolate the problem a bit better.

Comment: doing `[[0]*x]*y` creates a list of references to the same sub-list, you need to use comprehension like `vals = [[0]*len(K_values) for _ in range(len(u_values))]` once you have that fixed you should consider using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to clean up those nasty loops: `for p,u in enumerate(u_values): for i,K in enumerate(K_values): ...`

Comment: Thank you very much @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen - your suggestion of using `vals = [[0]*len(K_values) for _ in range(len(u_values))]` works perfectly